# How to change Visual Studio Code C++ version through the GUI?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using C++ with Visual Studio Code. How do I change the C++ version (e.g. C++11, C++14, or other standard version) using the Visual Studio Code GUI? I don't want to mess around with JSON setting files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can change the C++ version in Visual Studio Code with the GUI. I am using a Mac with Visual Studio Code v1.60 (2021).

1. Make sure you have Microsoft's C/C++ Extension installed into Visual Studio Code.
2. Open the extension's settings, for example by right-clicking on the extension and then selecting "Extension Settings".

[image]

3. That will bring up a new tab called "Settings" with a search bar.

[image]

4. Add "cppStandard" to the search terms in the search bar.

[image]

5. That will filter the settings. Find a setting called `C_Cpp > Default: Cpp Standard`. Use the drop-down menu to select what version of C++ you want.

[image]